# Contact between two rigid bodies. How does contact force is distributed in the contact surface?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

We have a rigid body with some scalar function of vector argument, which describe density of body at concrete point in space.

The body lie on the table in the stable state, elements of it doesn't perform any movement. The body is situated on the uniform gravity field.

Example: Crown on the table upside down

If perform "infinite" sum for all "small elements" of the body, and remember 2nd,3rd Newton law then you can retrive that "Total Normal Force" from table "to body" is equal to -Mg. We retrieve magnitude and direction of that "main force" vector.

I'd like to know how can I split that "Integrate Total Normal Force" to parts as collection of "Normal Force", for example to count torque from all Ni external forces?

Comment: It is worth noting that when you start to examine problems in this kind of detail the notion of rigidity ends up becoming a little, well, squishy.

Comment: Please. Suggest where can I to read more about it?